# Query to identify combined therapies of the patient

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am a beginner in SQL and I'm struggling with this exercise.
I want to identify patients treatments based on receipt history. I want to compute the monotherapies or combined therapies the patient is following and for what periods.

I have attached a picture showing the Input and Output.

[image]

```sql
WITH TreatmentCTE AS (
    SELECT
        PatientId,
        DrugName,
        StartDate,
        EndDate,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PatientId ORDER BY StartDate) -
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PatientId, DrugName ORDER BY StartDate) AS GroupNum
    FROM
        Exercise
)

SELECT
    PatientId,
    STRING_AGG(DrugName, '+') AS Treatment,
    MIN(StartDate) AS StartDate,
    MAX(EndDate) AS EndDate
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
    StartDate,
    EndDate,
        PatientId,
        GroupNum,
        DrugName
    FROM
        TreatmentCTE
) AS DistinctDrugs
GROUP BY
    PatientId,
    GroupNum
ORDER BY
    PatientId,
    StartDate;
```

I have created the above query but the result is not the desired one. The columns 'Treatment' is not as in the output but shows 'A+A+A' when it should be only one 'A'. Using distinct is not allowed with STRING_AGG.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Hi - 1) Please don't use images, add all source/result data as editable text, formatted as tables 2) Please update your question to show show the output you are getting with your current query

Comment: Look at the `groupnum` values coming out of the CTE and I think you'll find the answer. Are you trying to figure out when different therapies overlapped?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `DISTINCT` on the `DrugName` inside the subquery, I think this is the main problem.

Try this approach with HAVING:

```sql
WITH TreatmentCTE AS (
    SELECT
        PatientId,
        DrugName,
        StartDate,
        EndDate,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PatientId ORDER BY StartDate) -
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PatientId, DrugName ORDER BY StartDate) AS GroupNum
    FROM
        Exercise
)

SELECT
    PatientId,
    STRING_AGG(DrugName, '+') AS Treatment,
    MIN(StartDate) AS StartDate,
    MAX(EndDate) AS EndDate
FROM (
    SELECT
        PatientId,
        MIN(StartDate) AS StartDate,
        MAX(EndDate) AS EndDate,
        DrugName
    FROM
        TreatmentCTE
    GROUP BY
        PatientId,
        DrugName,
        GroupNum
    HAVING
        COUNT(DISTINCT GroupNum) = 1
) AS Monotherapy
GROUP BY
    PatientId,
    StartDate,
    EndDate
ORDER BY
    PatientId,
    StartDate;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with X as (
    select *,
        lead(DrugName)  over (partition by PatientId order by StartDate, EndDate) as nextDrug,
        lead(StartDate) over (partition by PatientId order by StartDate, EndDate) as nextStart,
        lead(EndDate)   over (partition by PatientId order by StartDate, EndDate) as nextEnd
    from Exercise
), Y as (
    select *,
        -- you may just want to combine these into a single range test
        case when DrugName  = nextDrug and EndDate = nextStart then 0
             when DrugName <> nextDrug and nextStart between StartDate and EndDate then 0
             else 1 end as flag
    from X
), Z as (
    select *, sum(flag) over (partition by PatientId order by StartDate, EndDate) as grp
    from Y
),  ZZ as ( -- duplicate drugs are eliminated here
    select PatientId, DrugName, grp,
        min(StartDate) as minStartDate, max(EndDate) as maxEndDate
    from Z
    group by PatientId, DrugName, grp
)
select PatientId,
    string_agg(DrugName, '+') as Treatment,
    min(minStartDate) as StartDate, max(maxEndDate) as EndDate
from ZZ
group by PatientId, grp;
```

This handles some of your problems but there's also a question about how you want to handle a chain of therapies that don't fully overlap. *A* could coincide with *B* which then coincides with *C*. This method treats them all as a single block of treatment but I suspect you would want it to split *A+B* from *B+C*.

https://dbfiddle.uk/qUTbjyKn